# A question about a paper of Boekstedt and Neeman

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am reading the paper of Boekstedt and Neeman

Homotopy limits in triangulated categories Compositio Math. 86 (1993) 209-234

In Page 230, there is the following statement. Let $X$ be an affine sheme and let $D(X)$ be the unbounded derived category of $O_X$-modules. Let $Y$ be a closed subset and $U$ be its complement. Denote by $D_Y(X)$ be the full subcategory of complexes of sheaves with support in $Y$. Then this subcategory is localising and colocalising. I know that it is localising. My question is how to prove that it is colocalising, that is (if I understand well), $D_Y(X)$ is closed under infinite products in $D(X)$. I understand that the support of a complex of sheaves is the union of the supports of its cohomology groups.